# Read huge XML/GML and XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, gml

I want to find a strong program that can read big XML/GML files and that I can simply search in. I have a file that is 240 mb big but I can't find any software that can do this.

The use-case is simple: Load in a big file and search to find things with XPath. That's it!

Do you have any recommendations for this? I have tried XML Editor(where XPath doesn't work) and Liquid XML where XPath is automatically disabled due to performance(too big XML file).

Answer (score 0):

Oxigen XML editor also manage 1G xml but its not free
https://www.oxygenxml.com/

Answer (score 0):

250Mb is about at the limit of what you can handle comfortably in Saxon without streaming - it should be possible given 2Gb of memory (you would have to build your own Java app to load the data and then accept searches and display the result). If the XPath expressions are simple enough, then the enterprise edition of Saxon has the ability to evaluate XPath in streaming mode, that is, during a single pass of the document without building the whole document tree in memory. But the way you describe the problem, it sounds as if you want to run multiple searches on the document, in which case a solution that allocates memory to the tree is probably better.

One thing you could attempt is to filter the document during loading to eliminate parts that aren't needed; if you could cut it by half to 120Mb, most of your problems would disappear.